# "could not initialize proxy - no Session" when calling from a CustomScope

Tags: hibernate, session, jpa, lazy-evaluation

I'm facing a little problem when calling a repository from a Controller which is annotated as this (this Controller is in the server "web-admin-service" which is an admin panel)

```
@Named
@Scope("view")
public class PlaceController implements Serializable {}
```

To show you an example I have these entities in my service (web-service)
University and Student

```
public class University {
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private String address;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Student> students;

 // setters and getters
}
```

Now when I call from the Controller my DAO which will call a method on a JPA repository (A simple `SELECT u FROM University u) the students List is not filled and has this error:
**"could not initialize proxy - no Session"**

But.. When I make the exact same call but within my service directly , i do not have this problem?
Even if fetch = FetchType.LAZY my students List is filled correctly when I call students.get(0).getName();

ps: I am using Spring, JPa and Hibernate

Comment: change fetchType to Eager...Then it will work, short term solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i would be more interested by the long term solution.  How can make hibernate stop closing the session like this?

Comment: Using a Eager is not a problem as such...It is only a problem if the load on your server is too high....In that way I meant it.